# Word Add-in works in MSWord 2016 and in Visual Studio sandbox but not in Word for Office 365

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js

I am trying to debug a word javascript add-in written by another developer that was working in Word 2016. But when our organization adopted O365 it stopped working there. It's possible that our org (Penn State) is blocking some functionality, and also possible that the issue is related to our Single Sign On (Cosign). The add-in *does* work when I run it in a brand new stand-alone Visual Studio 2017 Word add-in project (same version of MS-Word, obviously).

I've tried debugging the code using VS and the failure seems to occur deep in the Office.onReady() function. At that point the Office object has been instantiated but not the Word object. The failure appears as "Unable to get property 'run' of undefined or null reference" the first time Word.run is called

Here is the manifest.xlm file:

```
    <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
               <Id>e69eaa23-19f3-48fd-9f8e-694eb013e433</Id>
        <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
        <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
        <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
        <DisplayName DefaultValue="PSU Indexing" />
        <Description DefaultValue="Manage and create document indexes." />
        <Hosts>
            <Host Name="Document"/>
        </Hosts>
        <DefaultSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="C:\PSUIndexer\home.html" />
        </DefaultSettings>
        <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
    </OfficeApp>
```

and here is the beginning of the main.js file that contains most of the javascript code for the add-in:

```
    "use strict";

    // The initialize function is run each time the page is loaded.
    Office.onReady(function() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            try {
                // Use this to check whether the API is supported in the Word client.
                if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)) {
                    // alert supported version
                    $('#system_notes').html("<p>Word version check successful. System ready to use.</p>");

                    Init();

            ... // some more code here but it's already failed at this point
                }
                else {
                    // Just letting you know that this code will not work with your version of Word.
                    $('#system_notes').append('<p>This system requires Word 2016 or greater. Some parts may not function.</p>');
                }

            } catch(e) {
                OutputText(e.message);
            }
        });
    });

    function Init() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
        ... // init code goes here
        return context.sync();
        }).catch(handleError);
    }
```

The initial error occurs at word-win32-16.01.js (line 24, column 346444): "Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference." The object being referenced is localstorage; I think that's because the installation references html and javascript in the local filesystem -- later we will want to host this on a webserver somewhere but for now and in the past this was the way it was installed. Since the Word object is not instantiated, the Word.run function in Init() fails, and no javascript will run after that.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Just a thought bcoz it is JS . Can you open a cmd prompt from the cloned folder. And type code . . It will open up the VSCode(should be installed first). Then do the npm install then do `npm start` and let me know the results

Comment: I hadn't installed Node but I will try that and let you know, thanks!

Comment: OK installed and started npm. The original project does not include package.json or bsconfig.json so I borrowed them from another project (a microsoft word add-in tutorial) and don't know if they're appropriate. if I open https://localhost:3004/home.html it does not work: the original onReady code does not run.